Can the calendar dates of the 4 yugas be inferred from scripture?
Wiki says:

According to Puranic sources,[a] Krishna's death marked the end of Dvapara Yuga and the start of Kali Yuga, which is dated to 17/18 February 3102 BCE.

Does scripture have the information to assign calendar dates to the start and end dates of the 4 yugas?
